# How can I use mysqli_fetch_array() twice?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using the entries from a database to fill a row and a column in a table. But I cannot access the SQL returned data twice using `mysqli_fetch_array()` twice. I need to loop mysqli result more than once. This doesn't work:

```
//Copy the result
$db_res = mysqli_query( $db_link, $sql );
$db_res2=$db_res;

//Top row
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $db_res, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
        echo "<td>". $row['Title'] . "</td>";
}

//leftmost column
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $db_res2, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
                    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>". $row['Title'] . "</td>";
                    .....
                    echo "</tr>";
}
```

How can I apply `mysqli_fetch_array` twice on the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `while` loop and you don't need to use `mysqli_fetch_array()` at all!

You can simply loop on the `mysqli_result` object itself many times. It implements `Traversable` interface that allows it to be used in `foreach`.

```
//Top row
foreach($db_res as $row) {
    echo "<td>". $row['Title'] . "</td>";
}

//leftmost column
foreach($db_res as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row['Title'] . "</td>";
    .....
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

However, you should separate your DB logic from your display logic and to achieve this it is best to use `fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` in your DB logic to retrieve all records into an array.

If you fetch all the data into an array, you can loop that array as many times as you want.

```
$data = $db_res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($data as $row) {
    // logic here...
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You should always separate data manipulations from output.

**Select your data first:**

```
$db_res = mysqli_query( $db_link, $sql );
$data   = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db_res))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Note that since PHP 5.3 you can use `fetch_all()` instead of the explicit loop:

```
$db_res = mysqli_query( $db_link, $sql );
$data   = $db_res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

**Then use it as many times as you wish:**

```
//Top row
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    echo "<td>". $row['Title'] . "</td>";
}

//leftmost column
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row['Title'] . "</td>";
    .....
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: As long as no `mysqli_free_result()` is used, this solution would just double the memory used by the query.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. `mysqli_fetch_array()` moves the pointer forward each time you call it. You need [`mysqli_data_seek()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) to set the pointer back to the start and then call `mysqli_fetch_array()` again.

So before calling the function a second time, do:

```
mysqli_data_seek($db_res, 0);
```

Comment: The answer might be problematic when you call `mysqli_data_seek($db_res, 0);` while still looping trough the results. Then it will run "forever".

Comment: @powtac They are not putting this in the loop, but rather after it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$squery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");

while($s = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
 ....
}
// add this line
mysqli_data_seek( $query, 0 );

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
 ...
}
```

try it.....