# Error Using mysqli_data_seek when using Do While Procedure

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting error on my first record when using mysqli_data_seek
This is the error i get:
[image: This is the error i get]

here is my first code

```
 <option value="">-</option>
    <?php do {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row3['nama_p'];?>" <?php if($row3['nama_p']==$row2['prov_domisili']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $row3['nama_p'];?></option>

    
    
    <?php } while ($row3= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3));?>
    <?php mysqli_data_seek($result3,0);?>
    
    
    
  </select></td>
```

And this is the second code to using the same mysqli data

```
<select name="textfield14" id="textfield14">
      >
      
    <option value="">-</option>
      
    <?php do {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row3['nama_p'];?>" <?php if($row3['nama_p']==$row2['prov_ktp']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $row3['nama_p'];?></option>
      
    <?php } while ($row3= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3));?>
      
      
  </select>
```

Here is the error I get:

> **Warning**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **C:xampp8htdocsvaksincovidpgeasicdata3.php** on line **300**

Comment: You never never ever ever need mysqli_data_seek()

Comment: Please quote your error messages as text, verbatim. There is absolutely zero advantage in showing a _screenshot_ of the error message here.

Comment: Why are you using `do … while` loops here? Unless you already fetched the data from the first record before this, how should `$row3` contain anything sensible here, in your first loop iteration?

Comment: If you are relying on the value of `$row3` after the loop finishes, it will already be null which is what stops the loop.  You HAVE to fetch a row again before using the value.

Comment: Why aren't you simply using `foreach` loops?

Comment: Please explain better what you are trying to do. At the moment, I am unclear as to what kind of answer you are looking for

Comment: i really want to know why this error occur when using `do...while`, i think best answer to solve this problem is to using `foreach` thanks for all your responses

Comment: I don't know what you were trying to do with do..while but here is how to use foreach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720568/how-can-i-use-mysqli-fetch-array-twice The do..while as explained has undefined variables in the first iteration which has nothing to do with seek_data function